# Python write an if statement that extracts text from data frame column and shifts values accordingly

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, if-statement, extract

I have data in a txt. file that imports like this once I split it into columns:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.read_csv(r'df.txt', header=None)
df.columns = ['Test']
df.drop(wells.tail(1).index, inplace = True)
df = df.Test.str.split(expand=True)

 0          1         2              3          4           5          6
Name        3      20201117         0.00       0.00       0.00 
Name      text        1           20090307     757.69     0.00    2060.00 
Name      text        2           20090308    1141.72     0.00    2099.00 
Name        2      20200908         0.00       0.00       0.00
```

I need to write an if statement for my data frame where, **if there is text column#1**, the text is merged into column#0, and those rows all shift as well:

```
 0          1         2            3          4           5        
Name        3      20201117       0.00       0.00       0.00 
Name text   1      20090307       757.69     0.00    2060.00 
Name text   2      20090308      1141.72     0.00    2099.00 
Name        2      20200908       0.00       0.00       0.00
```

I need this in an "if" statement format as I am running multiple files of the same format through the code, not all of which have text in column#1. Was trying to use str.extract() but couldn't figure it out.

Comment: Does assigning `quotechar='"'` in `pd.read_csv()` work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```pyton
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'0': {0: 'Name', 1: 'Name', 2: 'Name', 3: 'Name'},
   ...:  '1': {0: '3', 1: 'text', 2: 'text', 3: '2'},
   ...:  '2': {0: 20201117, 1: 1, 2: 2, 3: 20200908},
   ...:  '3': {0: 0.0, 1: 20090307.0, 2: 20090308.0, 3: 0.0},
   ...:  '4': {0: 0.0, 1: 757.69, 2: 1141.72, 3: 0.0},
   ...:  '5': {0: 0.0, 1: 0.0, 2: 0.0, 3: 0.0},
   ...:  '6': {0: np.nan, 1: 2060.0, 2: 2099.0, 3: np.nan}})

In [3]: df
Out[3]: 
      0     1         2           3        4    5       6
0  Name     3  20201117         0.0     0.00  0.0     NaN
1  Name  text         1  20090307.0   757.69  0.0  2060.0
2  Name  text         2  20090308.0  1141.72  0.0  2099.0
3  Name     2  20200908         0.0     0.00  0.0     NaN

In [4]: x = df.iloc[:, 1]
   ...: rows = x[~x.str.isnumeric()].index.to_list()
   ...: df1 = df.drop(rows).iloc[:, :-1]
   ...: df = df.iloc[rows]
   ...: s = df.iloc[:, :2].agg(" ".join, axis=1)
   ...: s.index = df.index
   ...: df = df.iloc[:, 1:]
   ...: df.iloc[:, 0] = s
   ...: df.columns = df1.columns
   ...: df = pd.concat([df, df1]).sort_index()
   ...: df
Out[4]: 
           0  1           2        3    4       5
0       Name  3  20201117.0     0.00  0.0     0.0
1  Name text  1  20090307.0   757.69  0.0  2060.0
2  Name text  2  20090308.0  1141.72  0.0  2099.0
3       Name  2  20200908.0     0.00  0.0     0.0
```

Comment: Hi @Amir wanted to follow up. Some files I am using don't have text that is split in Col1, and now as a result, the last column in the df is being deleted. Is there a way to make this an if statement function - such that if there is no text in col1, no shift is required?

Answer (score 0):

You can transpose the dataframe with `.T`, so you can work with `shift()` so that you can shift the data if there are `any` values that have `text`. Then `dropna()` to get rid of last row and use `T` again:

```
df = df.T
for col in df.columns:
    if df[col].str.contains('text').any():
        df.iloc[1][col] = df[col].iloc[0] + ' ' + df[col].iloc[1]
        df[col] = df[col].shift(-1)
df = df.dropna().T
df
1
2
Out[1]: 
           0  1            2        3  4     5
0       Name  3     20201117        0  0     0
1  Name text  1  2.00903e+07   757.69  0  2060
2  Name text  2  2.00903e+07  1141.72  0  2099
3       Name  2     20200908        0  0     0
```

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I tried your code and for some reason it ends up just deleting the 5th column.. not sure why, might just be an issue on my end. The other answer posted here worked, so either way no worries and appreciate your help.